# Get data from a server in a controller and share it with other controller to update the view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a complex application that needs to update the view from data retrieved from a server.

First, I retrieve the data in a controller called "EditController":

```
self.loadIndividualData = function(individual){
   this.srchByID.classById().get({_id: individual.id_class}, 
        function(res){
            auxiliarVariables.instanceClass = angular.copy(res);
        });}
```

I use ngResource to make the call. The variable "auxiliarVariables" is a service that makes possible to share the data between different controllers. So, then, I have in the other controller called "individualController" the following code:

```
self.instanceClass = auxiliarVariables.instanceClass;
```

Finally, in the view:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item class">
    <span ng-repeat="classId in VIndividualCtrl.instanceClass.ids">
      {{classId}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem that I found is that the view is not refreshed when the variable "instanceClass" changes. So when it takes longer to retrieve the data that to load the view (it is a modal), the variable is not shown.

If I initiate the "auxiliarVariables.instanceClass" to an array and then I use the method push inside the get call, then it works perfectly. It would look like:

```
 self.loadIndividualData = function(individual){
       this.srchByID.classById().get({_id: individual.id_class}, 
            function(res){
                auxiliarVariables.instanceClass.push(res);
            });
 }
```

The problem is that I do not want this variable to be an array. Is there any other solution?

Comment: it *sounds like* `instanceClass` is a Primitive, and `self.instanceClass = auxiliarVariables.instanceClass;` is making a copy *by value* instead of *by reference*.  If you can't make `instanceClass` an Object instead of a Primitive, then you would need to reference the `auxiliarVariables` Object instead, for *byRef* to work.

Comment: You are right, I did not realise before. Thank you!